# Method that creates new array only from the even numbers in Java

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

I am trying to create method that creates new array only from the even numbers from another array. However, I do not understand why I have the right length (only with the number of the even numbers) of my output array, but I have 0s instead of the actual numbers.

I know that the problem is simple, but right now I am stuck with it.

```
  import java.util.*;
    public class test{
    public static int [] myMethod(int []arr){
        int [] temp;
        int howManyEven = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(arr[i]%2==0){
                howManyEven++;
            }
        }
        temp = new int [howManyEven];
        int evenNum = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
        boolean even = false;

            for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
                if(arr[j]%2==0){
                    even = true;
                    evenNum = arr[j];
                }
               }
            if(!even){
                temp[i]=evenNum;
               }

        }
        return temp;
    }
    public static void main (String[]args){
        int [] myArray = {5,5,8,9,7,4,4,2,3};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myMethod(myArray)));

    }
}
```

Comment: There's a tool called as debugger for such problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second part of your `myMethod`, where there is nested for loop, your outer loop should iterate over `arr`. It can be simplified to below

```
    temp = new int [howManyEven];
    int j = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]%2 == 0) {
            temp[j++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
```

Better you can use java collections and finish the work in single loop

```
public static Integer[] myMethod(int []arr){ //notice the return type is Integer[] instead of int[]
    List<Integer> evens = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int a : arr) {
        if(a%2 == 0) {
            evens.add(a);
        }
    }
    return evens.toArray(new Integer[evens.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be `myMethod` should create a temparory list which collects the even numbers from the input array and then convert it to an output array containing only the even elements which should be returned to the caller

Working Example

```
 public static void main(String... str) {
        // results array has only even numbers
        Integer[] results = myMethod(new int[]{5, 5, 8, 9, 7, 4, 4, 2, 3});
        for(int i=0;i<results.length;i++)
            System.out.println(results[i]); // print each even number    
    }

    static Integer[] myMethod(int[] inputArray) {
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
            if (inputArray[i] % 2 == 0) {
                temp.add(inputArray[i]);
            }
        }
        return temp.toArray(new Integer[5]);
    }
```

Hope this code clarifies you well.

Answer (score 0):

Look again at this:

```
    if(!even){
        temp[i]=evenNum;
    }
```

I think you will notice yourself what's wrong.

Comment: Yes, I see now, this if statement is not even entered. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of processing the information twice for even numbers, you can create a List of integers which are 'even' and return that, or convert into primitive int[] and return that.

```
public static int[] myMethod(int[] arr) {

    List<Integer> even = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if(arr[i]%2==0){
            even.add(arr[i]);
        }


    }
    int []result = new int[even.toArray().length];
    Iterator it = even.iterator();

    int count=0;
    while(it.hasNext()){
        result[count++]=(int)it.next();
    }
    return result;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] myArray = {5, 5, 8, 9, 7, 4, 4, 2, 3};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myMethod(myArray)));

}
```

output

```
run:
[8, 4, 4, 2]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```